# Sorting answers by oldest

Tags: support

When sorting answers by oldest, does it go from when the answer was posted, or when it was last edited?

I answered a partial answer to a question, and while trying to work out the rest of the answer, another answer was posted, apparently within a few seconds of mine. I clicked to sort by oldest, to see if I had been ninja'd and it listed mine first. Later, after editing in the rest of the solution, I sorted by oldest again, and my answer was listed as being after the other.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/rad-enigma-based-upon-sketches?answertab=oldest#tab-top). Note that while sorting by oldest sorts answers by time of posting, the accepted answer is *always* at the top, regardless of when it was posted. ([Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188874/sort-answer-by-oldest-broken))

Comment: Yes, that's the question that triggered the question. That makes sense, but I didn't find that in a quick search of the help files.

Answer (score 2):

"Oldest" sorts by time of posting. If you want to sort by the time since the last edit, pick *active*.